# How to add custom annotation in swagger2 using with Springfox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0, springfox

i am using swagger2 and i want to create new @ApiSepecificationInfo annotation and this should be consider in auto generator of swagger2 doc(like if i hit Gradlw generatordoc)

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiSpecificationInfo {
   String name();
   String description();
}
```

please let me is this possible or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do custom annotation processing by implementing springfox [plugins](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#plugins).

If you implement the *OperationBuilderPlugin* interface springfox is providing you with all information you need.

```
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER)
public class OperationBuilderPluginImpl implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

    @Override
    public void apply(OperationContext context) {
        Optional<ApiOperation> methodAnnotation = context.findAnnotation(ApiSpecificationInfo.class);
        if (methodAnnotation.isPresent()) {
            ApiSpecificationInfo apiSpecificationInfo = methodAnnotation.get();
            // do your processing here
            context.operationBuilder().notes(apiSpecificationInfo.name());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
        return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
    }
}
```

See [github](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/cb79e9a34f7a72cd0b5010f9fcf58d27d6a7113f/springfox-swagger-common/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger/readers/operation/OperationNotesReader.java) for reference.

Comment: I believe you have an error in your code. it should be Optional<ApiSpecificationInfo> methodAnnotation = ...

Comment: also, important information: the annotation must have runtime retention. otherwise, it won't be visible to swagger.